# How can I add a (CSS) cursor: property to elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

I am trying to style the data array, so that when you hover over it the cursor is set to `cursor: grab;`. I tried using different elements to make it happen none worked ,
`.li{}`, `.ol{}`, `MediaComponent{}`,`img{}`,`imgSrc{}`,`data{}`,`div{}`. The only one that worked for me was `*.{}`, however the problem with this is that the cursor remains on the grab property for the rest of the elements on the page. I'm trying to code it so that the  `cursor:grab;` element only pertains to the data array.

```
import React, { Component,useRef, setStatus, status } from 'react';
import './Turkish.css';

import turk1 from "./music/turk1.mp3";
import turk2 from "./music/turk2.mp3"
import turk3 from "./music/turk3.mp3"
import turk4 from "./music/turk4.mp3"

const data = [
    { imgSrc: 'turk1.png', audioSrc: turk1 },
    { imgSrc: 'turk2.png', audioSrc: turk3 },
    { imgSrc: 'turk3.png', audioSrc: turk4 },
    { imgSrc: 'turk4.png', audioSrc: turk2 },
  ];
  
  export default class Turkish extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ol>
            {data.map(({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => (
              <MediaComponent imgSrc={imgSrc} audioSrc={audioSrc} />
            ))}
          </ol>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  const MediaComponent = ({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => {
    const audioRef = useRef(null);
    const toggleAudio = () =>
      audioRef.current === null
        ? console.log("Audio component is not loaded yet.")
        : audioRef.current.paused
        ? audioRef.current.play()
        : audioRef.current.pause();

        
            return (
              <li>
                <img src={imgSrc} onClick={toggleAudio} />
                <audio
                  ref={audioRef}
                  src={audioSrc}
                  onLoad={() => setStatus({ ...status, isLoaded: true })}
                  onPlay={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: true })}
                  onPause={() => setStatus({ ...status, isPlaying: false })}
                  onError={() => setStatus({ ...status, error: true })}
                />
              </li>
            );
          };
```

Any thoughts?

Thank You

-Zpo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `ol`, I guess you are making mistake in your CSS file. To be sure give className to your `ol` and pass `cursor: grab` in CSS

```
<ol className="olGrab">
   {data.map(({ imgSrc, audioSrc }) => (
    <MediaComponent imgSrc={imgSrc} audioSrc={audioSrc} />
   ))}
</ol>
```

In CSS

```
.olGrab { cursor: grab;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still doesn't work. There anything i'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Check here i used same approach and it works fine https://codesandbox.io/embed/solitary-brook-mtlem7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Very intresting! Is there any way you can make an example out of my code? I tried it out again and it ain't working

Comment: It is already your code, the component inside the map will not change the result. Can you edit your code with my suggestion and share also your css here please? @zpodavay

Comment: You're correct, appreciate it !!